# Remove shadow in KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

Is there a way to remove the applied shadow from Kinetic.Shape?
unfortunately shape.setShadow(null) doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you use var s = shape.getShadow(); var l = shape.getLayer(); l.remove(s); ?

Comment: @Jonke: I tied it but didn't work!

Comment: can you make a small jsfiddle that reproduce your problem? or insert some code in you post?

Comment: I took a quick look at the code behind and setShadow and I'm not sure butI think that the config object gets merged with whatever is already stored. Maybe one could manipulate the returned obj of shape.getShadow() before using setShadow and 'restore' it to the default, depending on how kineticjs merge function for config objects actually work.

Comment: I think it would be nice to have an easy way to remove the shadow from a shape. Something like shape.setShadow(null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the shadow color's alpha component to 0 (e.g.):

```
shape.setShadow({color: 'rgba(80, 80, 80, 0)'})
```

Comment: It works but technically it doesn't remove the shadow. It just makes it transparent.
But it solved my problem :)

Comment: This can't be the only way? Is there no better way?

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic.js now has a `setShadowEnabled` method.

So, just call `shape.setShadowEnabled(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
shape.setShadowColor('transparent');
```